# What does the @ symbol mean in R?

Tags: r, r-s4

In packages like marray and [limma](http://bioinf.wehi.edu.au/limma/), when complex objects are loaded, they contain "members variables" that are accessed using the @ symbol. What does this mean and how does it differ from the $ symbol?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

See `?'@'`:

- Description:

  Extract the contents of a slot in a object with a formal (S4)
  class structure.
- Usage:

  `object@name`

  ...

---

The S language has two object systems, known informally as S3 and S4.

- S3 objects, classes and methods have been available in R
  from the beginning, they are informal, yet *very interactive*.
  S3 was first described in the *White Book* (Statistical Models in S).
- S3 is not a real class system, it mostly is a set of naming
  conventions.
- S4 objects, classes and methods are much more formal and
  rigorous, hence *less interactive*. S4 was first described
  in the *Green Book* (Programming with Data). In R it is
  available through the `methods` package, attached by default
  since version 1.7.0.

See also this document: [S4 Classes and Methods](http://www.ci.tuwien.ac.at/Conferences/useR-2004/Keynotes/Leisch.pdf).

Answer (score 10):

As the others have said, the @ symbol is used with S4 classes, but here is a note from [Google's R Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml): "Use S3 objects and methods unless there is a strong reason to use S4 objects or methods."

Answer (score 5):

You will want to read up on S4 classes which use the @ symbol.