# R Programming: What is this code doing --> colSums(model@xmatrix[[1]] * model@coef[[1]])

Tags: r, vector, indexing, syntax

I have the following R code below:

```
# call ksvm
model <-  ksvm(as.matrix(data[,1:10]),as.factor(data[,11]),type="C- svc",kernel="vanilladot",C=100,scaled=TRUE)

# calculate a1.am
a <- colSums(model@xmatrix[[1]] * model@coef[[1]])
```

I'm trying to understand what this piece of code is doing:

```
colSums(model@xmatrix[[1]] * model@coef[[1]])
```

A detailed breakdown would be appreciated.

Comment: There are some information on the use of `@` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908010/what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-r). Can you add the package for the `ksvm` function and some reproducible data?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.