# What does @lx[i] mean in R?

Tags: r, shiny

So i looked into a guy's code and i saw these lines of code:

```
for(i in 1:getOmega(bh_w_f) + 1){
        bh_w_f_qx[i] = (bh_w_f@lx[i] - bh_w_f@lx[i + 1])/bh_w_f@lx[i]
```

What does `@lx[i]` mean or do? I tried look it up on the internet but i could not find anything. Any ideas? I want to mention that these lines of code above are the first occurance of `@lx[i]` or `lx[i]` or `lx` alone, so no declaration before. I ran the code and it works, no error given, the function works properly.
`bh_w_f_qx` and `bh_w_f` are vectors declared before

**EDIT :** As said in the comments and in the first answer, `bh_w_f` is actually a S4 object, a lifetable made with function `probs2lifetable` from https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lifecontingencies/versions/1.3.7/topics/probs2lifetable but i could not find what lx wants to be. As i said, it's the first time that `lx` shows up in the code, with no external files included.

**EDIT 2**: Found out that the answer is in the returning format from `probs2lifetable()` function, that returns a `lifetable class` object which has `lx`as *representing the number of lives at the beginning of age (x).*
More about it here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lifecontingencies/versions/1.3.7/topics/lifetable-class
Thanks

Comment: `@` suggests these are S4 objects, not simple vectors.

Comment: does (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908010/what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-r) answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

`@` is the symbol used to pull attributes from S4 class objects in R. This syntax can be unusual because most people use S3 as it's simpler than S4. In the case of the code you posted, my guess is that you can get away with thinking of `@` as the equivalent of a `$` for lists and data frames etc.

Comment: not to pull attributes, it is used to access a slot by its name of your s4 class object